# How to align contents in tabbing in longtable?

Tags: longtable, alignment, tabbing

This is my code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, pdftex, english, 10.25pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}



\definecolor{color}{RGB}{0,0,225}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\centering\LARGE\textbf{Curriculum Vitae}\\
\vspace{1mm}
\normalsize
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
\begin{spacing}{0.9}
\begin{longtable}[l]{p{49mm}p{110mm}}
\arrayrulecolor{color}\toprule
\textbf{\underline{Further Qualifications}}\\
\textbf{Language}
 & \begin{tabbing} aaaaa ~~~~~~~~~~~~~\= jfldskfjsaf\\
English \> Fluent\\
\> (.....)\\
eada \> Fluent\\
aaaa \> Basic knowledge \end{tabbing}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

This is the generated pdf of the above code.
[image]

I would like the contents in the `tabbing` to be horizontally aligned with "Language" on the left. How to do it?
This is the result I want:
[image]
i.e. The line started with "aaaaa" should be on the same row as "Language".

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to not use tabbing?  Longtable is already organized into columns.  i suppose you already have several pages worth of tabbing formatted and don't convert to anything else.

Comment: @JohnKormylo (I am not sure what exactly you mean, so I will reply to your comment to the best of my understanding.) Most rows of this longtable have only two columns, the code I have here only generates part of the longtable. So is there some ways to change the number of columns midways through the longtable?

Comment: !) You can end one longtable and start another.   2) You can specify lots of columns but not use every one every row.  3) You can insert a tabular inside a longtable (no page breaks), possibly using \multicolumn.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Can you write an answer demonstrating this?

Answer (score 1):

Note the use of @{} to increase the space between columns.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, pdftex, english, 10.25pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not with my editor
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}

\definecolor{color}{RGB}{0,0,225}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\centering\LARGE\textbf{Curriculum Vitae}\\
\vspace{1mm}
\normalsize
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
\begin{spacing}{0.9}
\begin{longtable}[l]{lr@{\quad}l@{\hspace{50mm}}}
\arrayrulecolor{color}\toprule
\textbf{\underline{Further Qualifications}}\\
\textbf{Language} & aaaaa & jfldskfjsaf\\
 & English & Fluent\\
 & & (.....)\\
 & eada & Fluent\\
 & aaaa & Basic knowledge
\end{longtable}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For me, the line \usepackage[english]{babel} is essential, otherwise it would produce an error. Also the line starting with "aaaaa" is not aligned with Language for me.

Comment: All it does for me is slow down the compile.  As I said, it is editor dependent.